# Ionic run function AFTER html has loaded and AFTER api call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have a function called getPuzzle() that calls an API to get data. I want to use that data to modify a div. The issue is that this is all done in the constructor and so the html hasn't been loaded yet.

So I put the code that modifys the html into ionViewDidEnter, however then it runs before the call to the API and it's missing the data this.puzzle

How do I not run this code until the HTML has loaded completely and AFTER the API call?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPuzzle();
  }

getPuzzle() {
      //Get puzzle info
      this.puzzlesService.getPuzzle().subscribe((data) => {
        this.puzzleType = this.puzzlesService.puzzleType;
        this.puzzle = this.puzzlesService.puzzle;
      });
  }

ionViewDidEnter() {
    //Set first tab
    if (this.puzzleType == 'text') {
      new Vara("#text", "assets/fonts/vara/Satisfy/SatisfySL.json", [{
        text: this.puzzle,
        delay: 2000,
        x: 2
      }], {
        fontSize: 25,
        strokeWidth: 1.5,
        duration: 15000,
        color: "black"
      });
    }

  }
```

Comment: Run it inside API call. `this.puzzle = this.puzzlesService.puzzle;
      });` after this line.

Comment: the HTML isn't loaded at that time and it can't access the #text id

Comment: Why are you subscribing to `puzzlesService.getPuzzle()`, then ignoring the data? Seems fishy! Also, why is this component duplicating at least 3 properties of a service you have access to? `getPuzzle`, `puzzleType`, and `puzzle` exist for both this component and the puzzlesService. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Solution

This is pretty deep into the well of trying to use `RxJS` imperatively instead of decoratively (Which is a pretty major code-smell with RxJS). Even so, this is one way to ensure that `this.puzzlesService.getPuzzle()` inside `getPuzzle` has emitted before the code after `//Set first tab` is run.

```ts
letsGooooooo = new ReplaySubject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.getPuzzle();
}

getPuzzle() {
  //Get puzzle info
  this.puzzlesService.getPuzzle().subscribe((data) => {
    this.puzzleType = this.puzzlesService.puzzleType;
    this.puzzle = this.puzzlesService.puzzle;

    this.letsGooooooo.next("GOOOOOOO!");

  });
}

ionViewDidEnter() {

  this.letsGooooooo.pipe(
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(_ => {
    //Set first tab
    if (this.puzzleType == 'text') {
      new Vara(
        '#text',
        'assets/fonts/vara/Satisfy/SatisfySL.json',
        [
          {
            text: this.puzzle,
            delay: 2000,
            x: 2,
          },
        ],
        {
          fontSize: 25,
          strokeWidth: 1.5,
          duration: 15000,
          color: 'black',
        }
      );
    }
  });
  
}
```

---

### More Involved Solution

Fix your service so that `puzzlesService` cashes the current puzzle and puzzle type as an observable rather than properties. Then you don't need to re-implement all those functions locally.

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  // No local version of puzzlesService needed
}

ionViewDidEnter() {

  this.puzzlesService.getPuzzle().subscribe(puzzleData => {
    //Set first tab
    if (puzzleData.puzzleType == 'text') { // puzzleData.puzzleType instead of this.puzzleType
      new Vara(
        '#text',
        'assets/fonts/vara/Satisfy/SatisfySL.json',
        [
          {
            text: puzzleData.puzzle, // puzzleData.puzzle instead of this.puzzle
            delay: 2000,
            x: 2,
          },
        ],
        {
          fontSize: 25,
          strokeWidth: 1.5,
          duration: 15000,
          color: 'black',
        }
      );
    }
  });
  
}
```

Comment: seems i cant use ionviewdidenter either. if i just run the vara code without any variables it's still not long enough before the dom loads and #text still doesn't exist yet. Do you know if there is a wait to wait for a div to exist then execute code?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing lifecycle issues. So, a good way that you can do is to call a function after the result of the Api. And on your view you can use an interrogation to avoid data not ready on interpolation `{{ puzzle?.text }}`

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.getPuzzle();
}

getPuzzle() {
  //Get puzzle info
  this.puzzlesService.getPuzzle().subscribe((data) => {
    this.puzzleType = this.puzzlesService.puzzleType;
    this.puzzle = this.puzzlesService.puzzle;
    this.updateView(); 
  });
}

updateView() {      
  //Set first tab
  if (this.puzzleType == 'text') {
  new Vara("#text", "assets/fonts/vara/Satisfy/SatisfySL.json", [{
    text: this.puzzle,
    delay: 2000,
    x: 2 }],{
    fontSize: 25,
    strokeWidth: 1.5,
    duration: 15000,
    color: "black"
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. because that function can get called before the HTML has loaded and #text doesn't exist yet

Comment: I updated the answer... So, please take a look. And on your view you can use an interrogation to avoid data not ready on interpolation {{ puzzle?.text }}